# Kivy environment not working (No module named kivy)

Tags: python, environment-variables, kivy

So i'm installing kivy on a new pc and decide to create a new environment since it's what the documentation recommends (kivy_venv).

The environment itself works fine and kivy is installed in it ( tried using the pip show kivy)

After that I tried to just import kivy with Sublime text, and it gave me an error, so I assumed I had to just copy the Kivy location the the System variables. That also did not fix the issue 'No module named kivy' .

I looked around and some people said I had to do this:

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_USE_DEFAULTCONFIG']
import kivy
```

That also did nothing for me.

I have never created an environment for kivy so i'm guessing the problem has something to do with that, I just can't figure it out since it seems to be working fine. If you need anything else type a comment. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
Pip freeze:

appdirs==1.4.4
bleach==3.2.3
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
colorama==0.4.4
distlib==0.3.1
docutils==0.16
filelock==3.0.12
idna==2.10
keyring==22.0.1
packaging==20.8
pkginfo==1.7.0
Pygments==2.7.4
pyparsing==2.4.7
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
readme-renderer==28.0
requests==2.25.1
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
rfc3986==1.4.0
six==1.15.0
tqdm==4.56.0
twine==3.3.0
urllib3==1.26.3
virtualenv==20.4.0
webencodings==0.5.1

Pip Freeze in environment:

certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
docutils==0.16
idna==2.10
Kivy==2.0.0
kivy-deps.angle==0.3.0
kivy-deps.glew==0.3.0
kivy-deps.gstreamer==0.3.1
kivy-deps.sdl2==0.3.1
Kivy-examples==2.0.0
Kivy-Garden==0.1.4
Pillow==8.1.0
Pygments==2.7.4
pypiwin32==223
pywin32==300
requests==2.25.1
urllib3==1.26.3
```

(I put it as code to make it easier to read, ignore that)

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the environment in the console ? Using `source kivy_venv/bin/activate` ? After having run it, you should be able to build and compile it.

If it doesn't work, can you also show what a `pip freeze` results in?

Comment: So 'source kivy_venv/bin/activate' wont work but 'kivy_venv/Scripts/activate does, idk what's up with that. I have done it with the second method and it still won't do anything, though the environment does run in the console. For the freeze ill edit the post...